# Frame dragging Warp drive

Tags: warp-drives, frame-dragging

**Is it possible to use frame dragging to make a warp drive?**

For example: a space ship with "frame dragging generators" that constructively interfere between them to let space be dragged in the desired direction of travel.

[image]

Of course we should have a more sophisticated configuration to effectively make a warp-bubble so that there is no pesky time dilation. And to get significant frame dragging, maybe stack generators on top of each other so that the top one gets all the spin of the ones below it?

The big question is whether the matter of the spinning generators would [repel](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.03301) each other too much? Perhaps we could electrically charge opposite generators with opposite charge to cancel the repulsion, and keep the spaceship intact while holding on to the generators. Or is this theoretically impossible?

While warp drives usually require exotic matter, this way we could do it without negative mass, correct?

Comment: Just idea, near a black hole (below so-called static limit) the space-time is dragged by velocity higher than speed of light. This is similar to your configuration, however, there is a question how to use this phenomenon as this part of space-time cannot travel further from the black hole.

Comment: Thanks Martin, but I don't want to use black holes for the generators. Doesn't every rotating object generate frame-dragging? Of course we need a lot of it, so perhaps we can stack generators on top of each other.